# How to make SQL query return exact number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose there is a table with 3 rows for employee A and 2 rows for employee B. I need to write a query which will return exactly 3 rows for both the employee (i.e. a dummy row should be present for employee B)

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: I was trying to write a query.

Comment: you just want a single query or an entire procedure that will handle this case generally? Say, finds the item/employee with max number of rows out of all the items to be displayed and for any item with less number of rows than that, display dummy rows?

Comment: PL/SQL is only for stored procedures. A query uses "just" SQL.

Comment: 3 is the maximum number of rows needed. Some employees can have 3 rows, some can have 2 rows, some can have 1 row and so on. But no employee will have more than 3 rows.

Comment: You can make a left join on the same table...

Comment: I fail to see a point in doing it SQL-side.
This kind of problem is better handled by the UI layer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not completely clear to me (for instance, can "3 rows" be "8 rows" too), but some starting points:

### Set up

```
create table emprec
( emp_id number
, val    number
)

insert into emprec values ( 1, 15)

insert into emprec values ( 1, 16)

insert into emprec values ( 1, 17)

insert into emprec values ( 2, 18)

insert into emprec values ( 2, 19)
```

### Query

```
select driving_x_axis.counter
,      driving_y_axis.emp_id
,      emprec.val
from  ( select  level counter
        from    dual
        connect by level <= 3
      ) driving_x_axis
join  ( select distinct emp_id
        from   emprec
      ) driving_y_axis
on    1=1 /* Carthesian. */
left
outer
join  ( select emp_id
        ,      val
        ,      row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by val) rownumber
        from   emprec
      ) emprec
on    emprec.rownumber = driving_x_axis.counter
and   emprec.emp_id    = driving_y_axis.emp_id
```

### Result

```
1   1   15
2   1   16
3   1   17
1   2   18
2   2   19
3   2   <null>
```

Simpler alternatives may be possible; please elaborate on your question.

Comment: For Carthesian join you can use also `table1 CROSS JOIN table2`

Comment: Correctly, "cross join" is a good alternative for "join on 1=1".

Comment: hi @Nitish was this answer helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?